# Retaining Radio Button Value after submitting button using GET method

Tags: php, html

I am using method= "GET", I have 2 radio buttons.I want to retain the selected radio button value even After clicking my submit button.

This is something I have tried, but yet does not work. Can any1 plz help me . Thank u in advance.

```
VEG<input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice']=="veg") echo 'selected="seleceted"';?>value="veg" >
Nonveg<input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice']=="nonveg") echo 'selected="seleceted"';?>value="nonveg" ></td>
```

Plz help me solve this.

Comment: You have a typo in `selected="seleceted"`.  You also need a space after that attribute.  Take a look at your HTML after submitting the form to troubleshoot if you have valid markup.

Comment: Sorry I dint get u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Practice

```
    <?php 
    $vegChecked = NULL;
    $nonvegChecked = 'checked="checked"';
    if(isset($_GET['choice'])) {
       if($_GET['choice'] == 'veg') {
           $vegChecked = 'checked="checked"';
           $nonvegChecked = NULL;
       } else if($_GET['choice'] == 'nonveg') {
           $vegChecked = NULL;
       }
    }
    ?>

    VEG    <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php echo $vegChecked;?> value="veg" />
    Nonveg <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php echo $nonvegChecked;?> value="nonveg" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a nonveg as selected radio button by default?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selected="selected" try using checked.

For example :-

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice']=="nonveg") echo 'checked'; ?>value="nonveg" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax instead of form submission to avoid refreshing of the page  Or Set the value of radio button in session  while executing form submission PHP. like  `session_start();`

```
$_SESSION['choice'] = $_GET['choice'];
```

then check the value using if condition to set selected button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
VEG<input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice']=="veg") echo 'checked="checked"';?> value="veg" >
Nonveg<input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if (isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice']=="nonveg") echo 'checked="checked"';?> value="nonveg" >
```